Why define a macro constant as ((uint8_t)0) instead of just 0?
Recently, I watch the YYJSON library source code. Here is one of the macro definitions.
#define YYJSON_TYPE_NONE        ((uint8_t)0)        /* _____000 */

why not just define this macro as follow ?
#define YYJSON_TYPE_NONE        0

I want to know the underlying reason for this
#define YYJSON_TYPE_NONE        ((uint8_t)0)        /* _____000 */


They want the type to be uint8_t rather than int. Hard to tell why exactly they want this, perhaps to get rid of some compiler warnings.

Maybe the comment is a clue - 000 up...

Look for occurrences of YYJSON_TYPE_NONE in the source code. This will probably give some hints.

@HolyBlackCat can you give an example where it would fix a warning ? I mean even if you pass 0 (without the cast) to a function expecting a uint8_t, or assign 0 to a uint8_t variable, you wouldn't get a warning. Am I missing something ?

@wohlstad I'm just guessing, not sure if there are any actual warnings this affects.

@HolyBlackCat at first my guess was the same, but then I thought about what I wrote above. Also checked in Godbolt (see here). So I'm curious what's the real reason for this cast.

This reads like defensive casting of the variable to unsigned (which could be accomplished with a U), but also to state quite explicitly that it's going to be dealt with as a uint8 value, and is aggregated with the subtype field, forming a 5 used of 8 bits of a uint8_t. When you look at other code dealing with it, it's inside a uint64_t tag field so it's a real 'try to keep it as tight as possible' to avoid it being treated in a bad way. This is only supposition of the intent of the code, though.

The code defines a type typedef uint8_t yyjson_type; so perhaps they wanted the constants to have the same type, although perhaps it would have been neater to cast the constants to (yyjson_type).

That cast was expliclitly changed a few years ago from yyjson_type to uint8_t (https://github.com/ibireme/yyjson/commit/af4d49971c030cae997200768ae7c1bdaf3ba870). The person to ask is the developer.

All integer constants ("literals") of 0 etc are of type int in C. If you wish them to be of a larger type, you could append L/l, but no similar mechanism exists to turn them into a smaller type save for a cast.
Looking at the diff provided in comments, I would say that the developer is striving for type correctness and maybe to minimize the amount of implicit promotions. It even kind of seems like they are trying to recover from a previous bug fest caused by implicit promotions being present, but I'm speculating. They seem to have desired a change where the code would mainly use uint8_t in arithmetic everywhere. However, C is not that kind - it comes with some manner of implicit type promotion in almost every operator.
As some sort of rule of thumb: an unsigned value can be promoted implicitly to another unsigned type without harm. But in case it gets promoted to a signed type like int, there are some cases where that could cause bugs - most notably when the >> << ~ operators are used.
For example in (tag & YYJSON_SUBTYPE_MASK) >> YYJSON_TYPE_BIT. All operands here are of type uint8_t. However, tag & YYJSON_SUBTYPE_MASK gets implicitly promoted to int and the result of the shift expression is type int (the type of the promoted left operand). So we gained nothing from using uint8_t here.
There could also be a performance reason for using uint8_t. While there are promotions - if the compiler can conclude that the promotions have no side effects like change of sign - it can then optimize the expression to get carried out on 8 bit instructions exclusively and ignore the promotion to int. These kind of optimizations are frequently used for 8-bit CPU programming, as one example. For the more high end applications where this library is more likely to get used, uint8_t probably doesn't give any performance benefit - it could even give the contrary. The correct type to use if performance was the reason would be uint_fast8_t.

Can  i conclude from your answer that the code won't bug even if integer constants is't convered to uint8_t ?

@DaWang I've only seen the diff from a certain commit posted by someone, not the code itself.

I went to the library code, it seems they are creating flags, for annotating a JSON property type (after the macro definition show cited, there are more type flags).
There is no reason for me to start explaining about flags and bitwise operations here, but do read about them, because they are an important fundamentals in programming.
